# Why does ExecuteNonQuery return 0 values even the SQL Server stored procedure returns 1 row(s) affected?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a SQL Server stored procedure that updates a table.

Here's my stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_ExampleUpdate]
    (@iID INT,
     @sCodeName VARCHAR(MAX)
    )
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE dbo.Example
    SET CodeName = @sCodeName
    WHERE ID = @iID
END
```

When I execute this stored procedure in SQL Server, it returns "1 row(s) affected", and the data is updated. But when I'm trying to execute this stored procedure from ASP.NET MVC using `ExecuteNonQuery`, it returns 0.

Here's a sample of my code

```
public bool UpdateExample(SqlTransaction p_oTrans, int ID, string CodeName)
{
    try
    {
        int iRowAffected = SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(p_oTrans, "usp_ExampleUpdate", ID, CodeName);

         return (iRowAffected > 0);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

The `iRowAffected` here always return 0, even though the stored procedure is successfully executed.

I've read the about [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx), but I still don't get it, why I always get 0.

Comment: Have you try using SET NOCOUNT ON; in t-sql??

Comment: @SandeepMaharjan yep, but I still get 0

Comment: Are you sure the data isn't updated? Check the table itself.

Comment: @kabanus no, it isn't updated, because in my code, if `return (iRowAffected > 0)` return false, it will automatically rollback. So the data is not updated

Comment: @T.S. yep, but I do not used `SET NO COUNT ON` on my SP and not return -1 but 0

Comment: That's not what I meant but you have an answer now I think.

Comment: `return (iRowAffected > 0)` is based on wrong assumption. So, you rollback your trans and data is not saved. Again, based on wrong assumption that `ExecuteNonQuery` must return number of rows affected out of SP.

Comment: @kabanus yes, I think the rollback things is my answer, but all I don't get is why I get 0, when it's suppose to be 1

Comment: Did you try `SET NOCOUNT OFF` ??

Answer (score 0):

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx):

> For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the number of rows affected by the command. When a trigger exists on a table being inserted or updated, the return value includes the number of rows affected by both the insert or update operation and the number of rows affected by the trigger or triggers. **For all other types of statements, the return value is -1.** If a rollback occurs, the return value is also -1.

Since you're executing SP and not one of those 3 DML statements, I conclude that it works as designed

Comment: I've read this so many times, but I still don't get it, can you explain more?

Comment: Sorry, I can't. You can get  JetBrain's "dotPeek" application and look what `ExecuteNonQuery` does inside `System.Data` assembly during SP execution. I am satisfied with MS documentation. This is time-consuming and worthless activity. May be you can get some counts inside SP and return as parameter.

Comment: But it looks like the original poster IS using one of those 3 DML statements.  It's an Update statement. In addition, you actually want NOCOUNT OFF if you want to return the number of rows affected.SET NOCOUNT OFF;  
GO Ensure that your stored procedure is actually updating records.

Comment: @CharlesOwen This is tricky situation in which MS doesn't guarantee return number of rows affected out of SP. However, sometimes, you may get it.

Comment: Wait, is that mean the return of 0 value from `ExecuteNonQuery` is valid even the executed from SP has a rows affected (not 0 row(s) affected)?

Comment: @JTR the consensus is that if you add `SET NOCOUNT OFF` you will get number of rows affected [sometimes]. The bottom line is - MS doesn't guarantee accurate rows affected with `ExecuteNonQuery` and SP.